# Get number of emails sent daily by "no-reply email" using Nodemailer

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodemailer

We are currently using Nodemailer to send and receive emails within our company.  We recently have been exceeding our daily SMTP relays which means that some emails will not send.  I was asked to check how many emails our "no-reply" email sends on a daily basis to see if there is a reason we are exceeding these limits. Any suggestions and ideas would be greatly appreciated.

NOTE:  I'm new to Nodemailer and don't know much about it.

I've tried deciphering the existing code and can't make much sense out of it.  I figured that I would just create a counter that would increment every time there is a sendmail() request from that email, but I don't know how to send a daily report that states what that value is.

This is what's in our server.js file
NOTE: Some names have been modified for confidential purposes

```js
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: env.EMAIL.SERVICE,
    host: env.EMAIL.HOST,
    auth: {
        user:env.EMAIL.AUTH.USER,
        pass:env.EMAIL.AUTH.PASS
    }
});

app.get('*', function (request, response) {
    if (request.get('x-auth')) console.log("x-auth: ", request.get('xauth'));
    const proto = request.get('X-Forwarded-Proto');
    if (proto) {
        if (proto === 'http') response.redirect(301,"https://myapplication.net".concat(request.url));
    }
    response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../', 'public', 'index.html'))
    if ((request.url).substring(0, 5) == "/send") {
        var mailOptions = {
            to: request.query.to,
            bcc: request.query.bcc,
            subject: request.query.subject,
            text: request.query.text
        }
        //console.log(mailOptions); Read up on NodeMailer for details.
        smtpTransport.sendMail({  //email options
            from: " <noreply@someemail.com>", // sender address.  Must be the same as authenticated user if using Gmail.
            to: mailOptions.to, 
            bcc: " <noreply@someemail.com>",
            subject: mailOptions.subject, // subject
            html: mailOptions.text // body
        }, function (error, response) {  //callback
            if (error) {
                //console.log(error);
            } else {
                //console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
            }

            smtpTransport.close(); // shut down the connection pool, no more messages.  Comment this line out to continue sending emails.
        });
    }

});
```

I assume this is how it gets called

```js
var to = this.props.msgList.EmailTo;

var text = `<div>Hello from no-reply</div>`;

$.get("/send", { to: to, subject: 'Response Rates', text: text },function (data) { });
```

package.json

```js
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node src/entry",
    "start-dev": "npm-run-all --parallel build babel-node",
    "serve": "live-server public/",
    "build-linux": "clear && webpack && clear && yarn build-server && clear && yarn start",
    "build-windows": "cls && webpack && cls && yarn build-server && cls && yarn start",
    "build-server": "babel src/server -d src",
    "dev-server": "webpack-dev-server",
    "babel-node": "nodemon --exec babel-node src/server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "6.24.1",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.3",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "express": "latest",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "google-maps-react": "^2.0.2",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^3.4.2",
    "immutability-helper": "^2.4.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.14",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "node-schedule": "^1.3.2",
    "nodemailer": "^4.7.0",
    "normalize.css": "7.0.0",
    "npm": "^6.10.0",
    "promise-mysql": "^3.1.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-csv": "^1.0.14",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.14",
    "sass-loader": "6.0.6",
    "socket.io": "^2.0.3",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "twilio": "^3.24.0",
    "validator": "8.0.0",
    "webpack": "3.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.5.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: You should log all the output to a text file

Comment: @cullanrocks could you provide an example for this.

Comment: Just uncomment your console.logs and do this: node server.js > log-file.txt

Comment: @cullanrocks getting an error when running this.  is this the correct syntax: node ./src/server.js > log-file.txt?  The error I'm getting is Import React from 'react';

Comment: What's your entry point? How are you running the app? Post package.json?

Comment: @cullanrocks we have a script "build-windows" which looks like this in package.json: "build-windows": "cls && webpack && cls && yarn build-server && cls && yarn start"

Comment: Just post the whole file

Comment: ok just edited the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a counter as you stated an use something like node-scheduler [https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule] found here to setup a recurring event on a daily basis that both sends (via email? logged to console?) the value of the counter and resets it for the next day.

Comment: I gave it more thought and realize that I would have to have a state object within my server.js file and I don't think this would be a great idea.